# Pyspark 3.1.2 with hadoop 3.2 not working on windows 10

Tags: windows, hadoop, pyspark

I'm trying to write a parquet file using pyspark on a windows 10 machine. I have faced issues about winutils and all issue you can get but not found a solution. So my question is : as anyone managed to install pyspark 3.1.2 on windows 10 and run the following code :

```
from pyspark.sql import Row, SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
df = spark.createDataFrame([Row(a=1, b=2.)])
df.write.parquet("test.parquet")
```

What I have done so far :

1. Run the latest virtual box windows image from here https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/virtual-machines/
2. Installed python 3.9.7
3. run `pip install pyspark`
4. Added winutils and `HADOOP_HOME` (I've tested several versions.)
5. Tried to run the python code above.

It is explicitly said that pyspark can run on all systems `Spark runs on both Windows and UNIX-like systems (e.g. Linux, Mac OS)` : https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ but I did not find anyone who managed to run it.

**I manage to do this with the 3.0.1 version without any issue.**

Comment: What is the specific error you're getting? Why do you need a virtual machine? If you're actually downloading Spark from that web site, you shouldn't be using pip

Comment: I have been through errors where people advice to install vcredist, winutils, set specific environment variable, ....

It is not written here http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/ on which OS it may work. I did not find the documentation for os compatibility for pyspark.
Also I'm using a virtual machine to start with a clean environment since I'm not able to run it on my windows 10 computer or on my windows server 2019.

So what I'm asking is if there are people running pyspark on windows 10 or windows server 2019 able to execute the code writing a parquet.

Comment: Spark uses the JVM. The JVM works on almost any machine. Spark supports Java 11 and Python 3.9, as documented... I have been able to run PySpark code, yes, but my installation cannot help you, so  what specific errors are **you** getting? And if you're going to use a VM anyway, you'd have better luck using Linux

Comment: Also, if you read the , PyPi documentation for `pyspark` - _This Python packaged version of Spark is **suitable for interacting with an existing cluster**_, which sounds like you dont have